# Connect to ignite schema via SQLLine

Tags: ignite, gridgain, sqlline

After enabling authentication, able to login to SQLLine with passing the superuser i.e. ignite credentials. After logging I can see schemas like IGNITE, PUBLIC etc. Now, how I connect to any of the schema existing in the Ignite Cluster? Can I grant particular user to access the particular schema and does ignite super user has full access to any schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite does not have ACLs right now. Successful authentication means you are allowed to see and change everything.

GridGain, which is built on top of Ignite, has [some advanced security](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/security/security-audit), though.

Comment: But how to connect to particular schema or upon login how to change the schema?

Comment: You can use `jdbc:ignite:thin://host;schema=<SCH>` or just use dot notation. It is case sensitive so quoting it with double quotes often needed.

Comment: Is there any way to switch to another schema after login?

Comment: No, but you can hardcore it into your queries.